# Firebase timestamp .toDate() is not a fundction & Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, timestamp

I am trying to convert the timestamp of a firebase field but the error is not being removed, while the result is displaying well in the front-end, i have looked at almost all similar questions but none have helped me, here is what i have:

Vuex getter:

```
getCreatedAtTime(state){
      return moment(state.currentUser.createdAt.toDate()).format('LLL');  
    }
```

Current user object:

[image]

The result is showing fine but the errors are not disappearing, i have tried some other methods but they are not working.

Errors:

1 time: **state.currentUser.createdAt.toDate is not a function**

1 time: **Cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined"**

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that there errors are coming from the line specified? A bit more description and code would help for us to determine exact cause of the problem.If you are seeing result, that means there should be some problem elsewhere in the code.

Comment: From the return line, there is nothing in the components except mapGetter in computed property and displayed in the <p> tag, while currentUser is the object from firestore with the user data, one of them is also createdAt, other data are displayed without any problem.

Comment: Another thing i discovered is that if i go from /home to /settings route these errors do not appear but if i refresh in the /settings page the errors appear, i don't know why?

Comment: Probably the state is lost when you do refresh on settings page?

Comment: Nope, i have vuex-persistedState :/